# Media Fire Redirect link from href isn't working error code 500

Tags: html, mediafire

I have a mediafire file, I copied the share link and put it in the href like so:

```
<a class="btn btn-info" href="http://www.mediafire.com/file/not-real-file/not-real.exe/file" target="_blank">Windows Download (.exe)</a>
```

When it redirects to media fire it shows the following error:

[image: Media fire not working image]

When I upload an image to media fire it works, the problem appears to be with the .exe files specifically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error 500 is defined by default as an HTTP error encountered by the server. I suggest you look at the server log files or change the debug level of the server in order to see where exactly it falls over.

Other errors include: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status

Comment: This is the answer. I used localhost but when I uploaded it to a remote server it worked. Thanks